# AP is known to have two equation relations, how to find a [1] and tolerance d?

Tags: differential-equations

Arithmetic progression a [n], let s [n] be the sum of the first n terms of arithmetic progression a [n]

The known conditions of arithmetic progression are:

```
a[3] + a[4] == 12, s[3] == 9
```

The following code did not calculate a [1] and tolerance d

```
ClearAll["`*"]
a[n_] := a[1] + (n - 1) d; 
s[n_] := n (a[1] + a[n])/2; eqn = {a[3] + a[4] == 12, s[3] == 9};
Solve[eqn, {a[1], d}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code runs into a recursion limit when trying to evaluate `a[1]`, which is also shown as an error message:

> $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of a[1].

You have to restrict the definition of `a[n]` only to `n > 1` so that it does not apply to `a[1]`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d;
s[n_] := n (a[1] + a[n])/2;

eqn = {a[3] + a[4] == 12, s[3] == 9}
Solve[eqn, {a[1], d}]

(* {{a[1] -> 1, d -> 2}} *)
```

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
(*a[1]=1;*)
a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d; 
s[n_] := 
 n (a[1] + a[n])/2; eqn = {s[5] == s[2] + a[11], 
  a[1] == 1}; Solve[eqn, d]```Why is the calculation result an empty set in this situation?

Comment: Either (1) solve for both variables: `Solve[eqn, {d, a[1]}]`, or (2) separately define `a[1] = 1;` before `a[n_] := ...`, and then `eqn = {s[5] == s[2] + a[11]}; Solve[eqn, d]`

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d; 
s[n_] := 
 n (a[1] + a[n])/2; eqn = {s[5] == s[2] + a[11], 
  a[1] == 1}; Solve[eqn, {a[1], d}]```

Comment: Yes, that works as you can see by the result `{{a[1] -> 1, d -> 2}}`.

Comment: Why can't we treat a [1] as a variable? What are the properties of a [1]?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Writing `Solve[eqn, {a[1], d}]` is exactly that – treating `a[1]` as a "variable" to be solved for.

Comment: a[1] as a variable,```a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d;```Why is it not possible to calculate a [1] before adding n>1 in this code?Why runs into a recursion limit when trying to evaluate a[1]

Comment: Because that is how Mathematica works. If you define `a[n_] := a[1] + n` and then try to evaluate `a[1]`, this will run into recursion because it cannot evaluate `a[1]`. It will first do `a[1] + 1` then `(a[1] + 1) + 1` then `((a[1] + 1) + 1) + 1` then `(((a[1] + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1` and so on ...

Comment: Adding the condition of n>1 means that a [1] is not affected by recursive operations and the value of a [1] is fixed?

Comment: When you write `a[n_] := ...`, you provide a definition for all `a[n]`, including `a[1]`. When you write `a[n_ /; n>1]`, you provide a definition only for those `a[n]` which have `n>0`. This excludes `a[1]` which therefore remains "undefined".